# kubernetes: Service endpoints available from within cluster, not outside

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have a service (`LoadBalancer`) definition in a k8s cluster, that is exposing `80` and `443` ports.

In the `k8s` dashboard, it indicates that these are the external endpoints:

(the k8s has been deployed using rancher for what that matters)

```
<some_rancher_agent_public_ip>:80
<some_rancher_agent_public_ip>:443
```

Here comes the **weird** (?) part:

From a `busybox` pod spawned within the cluster:

```
wget <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>:80
wget <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>:443
```

both succeed (i.e they fetch the `index.html` file)

From outside the cluster:

```
Connecting to <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 

2018-01-05 17:42:51 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway.
```

I am assuming this is not a security groups issue given that:

- it **does** connect to `<some_rancher_agent_public_ip>:80`
- I have also tested this by allowing all traffic from all sources in the sg the instance with `<some_rancher_agent_public_ip>` belongs to

In addition, `nmap`-ing the above public ip, shows `80` and `443` in `open` state.

Any suggestions?

**update**:

```
$ kubectl describe svc ui
Name:                     ui
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert=arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:somecertid
Selector:                 els-pod=ui
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.43.74.106
LoadBalancer Ingress:     <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>, <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               %!d(string=ui-port)/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30854/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.179.14:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               %!d(string=ui-port)/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31404/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.179.14:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

and here is the respective pod description:

```
kubectl describe pod <the_pod_id>
Name:           <pod_id>
Namespace:      default
Node:           ran-agnt-02/<some_rancher_agent_public_ip>
Start Time:     Fri, 29 Dec 2017 16:48:42 +0200
Labels:         els-pod=ui
                pod-template-hash=375086521
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"ui-deployment-7c94db965","uid":"5cea65ea-eca7-11e7-b8e0-0203f78b...
Status:         Running
IP:             10.42.179.14
Created By:     ReplicaSet/ui-deployment-7c94db965
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/ui-deployment-7c94db965
Containers:
  ui:
    Container ID:   docker://some-container-id
    Image:          docker-registry/imagename
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://docker-registry/imagename@sha256:some-sha
    Port:           80/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 05 Jan 2018 16:24:56 +0200
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 05 Jan 2018 16:23:21 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 05 Jan 2018 16:23:31 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  5
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-8g7bv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          True 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  default-token-8g7bv:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-8g7bv
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of `kubectl describe svc <your_service_name>` ? Thanks!

Comment: question updated

Comment: Thanks. I believe that you are running on AWS. Can you see the LoadBalancer created in your AWS console? Normally, when using a service of type LoadBalancer, you wouldn't connect to the rancher agent public ip directly, but to the LoadBalancer IP, since it's the one that knows how to redirect the request from the client to the pod that you are trying to reach.

Comment: Since I am running it with Rancher, the service type = LoadBalancer created a `HAProxy`. When I run the same example with `kops` (instead of `rancher`) it created an aws elb

Comment: I guess sending a request to <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>:30854 works? 30854 is the `NodePort` of the `ui` service you described. That means, it's the port being exposed on every node of your k8s cluster.

Comment: Yes it does work! Why is this happening and I do not have `80` exposed?

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes provides different ways of exposing pods to outside the cluster, mainly `Services` and `Ingress`. I'll focus on `Services`since you are having issues with that.

There are different `Services` types, among those:

- **ClusterIP**: default type. Choosing this type means that your service gets an stable IP which is reachable only from inside of the cluster. Not relevant here.
- **NodePort**: Besides having a cluster-internal IP, **expose the service on a random port on each node of the cluster (the same port on each node)**. You’ll be able to contact the service on any NodeIP:NodePort address. That's why you can contact your `rancher_agent_public_ip:NodePort` from outside the cluster.
- **LoadBalancer**: Besides having a cluster-internal IP and exposing service on a NodePort, ask the cloud provider for a load balancer that exposes the service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer.

Creating a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` makes it `NodePort` as well. That's why you can reach `rancher_agent_public_ip:30854`.

I have no experience on rancher, but it seems that creating a `LoadBalancer` Service deploys a HAProxy to act as a Load balancer. That HAProxy that was created by Rancher needs a public IP thats reachable from outside the cluster, and a port that will redirect requests to the `NodePort`.

But in your service, the IP looks like an internal IP 10.43.74.106. That IP won't be reachable from outside the cluster. You need a public IP.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. However, in the svc description, doesn't this line indicate that the `HAProxy` lb takes an public IP?`LoadBalancer Ingress:     <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>, <some_rancher_agent_public_ip>`

Comment: I don't have experience with rancher so I can't tell :/